# Encode List to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, json

### The Goal

Encode a `List<T>Session["MySession"]` to JSON with Razor Engine.

### The Problem

I have the following script in my `Index.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var existingItems = 
        @Html.Raw
           (Json.Encode
              ((List<MyApp.Models.Data.getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>)
                  Session["ProdructsSummary"]))

    window.onload = function () {
        console.log(existingItems);
    }
</script>
```

And the return of `existingItems` is `null`. Why?

### Observation

*I'm sure* — there is a value on my Session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to cast to the underlying type. You could simply write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var existingItems = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["ProdructsSummary"]));

    window.onload = function () {
        console.log(existingItems);
    }
</script>
```

Now you are saying that this generates the following markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var existingItems = null;

    window.onload = function () {
        console.log(existingItems);
    }
</script>
```

What about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (Session["ProdructsSummary"] == null) 
    {
        <text>alert('the session is null');</text>
    }
</script>
```

Can you see the alert? I am sure you can see it. I am even ready to bet 5 bucks on it assuming your statement about getting null is true.

Conclusion: `Session["ProdructsSummary"]` is null so don't expect that `Json.Encode` will return something else.

Comment: Hm... Got it. But, that strange... I have a method that lists the items on my session. By the way, what is the solution? `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["ProdructsSummary"]))`?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["ProdructsSummary"]))`. You don't need to be casting. If you have something into the session the Json.Encode method will correctly serialize it to JSON without the need to explicitly telling the underlying type.

Comment: But Darin, `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["ProdructsSummary"]))` keeps returning me null. I understand your explanation (thanks for that), but I couldn't apply.

Comment: It's returning you null because `Session["ProdructsSummary"]` is null. Is it so difficult for you to understand that? You need to have some value inside `Session["ProductsSummary"]` if you expect to get this value out. It's not the fault of the Json.Encode helper. There's no value to encode.

Comment: Darin, was my bad. Look: `Session["ProdRuctsSummary"]`. Of course this doesn't exists. And yes, as I said: I understand your explanation. Thank you very much! +1

Comment: So it is a typo. Is there something else you would like to ask on this subject before marking the answer?

Comment: Yes, was a typo =( — sorry about this. Oh, Darin — thanks about the opportunity. I have another question yes, and its simple: there is a way to encoding to JSON directly on JavaScript? I mean, without @Html.Raw?

Comment: Why would you need a different way? `Json.Encode` is the correct way to pass server side models to javascript functions.

Comment: Darin, as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304720/shopping-cart-logic-trouble-with-knockoutjs#comment25124265_17307483), I need to load the values of the session with KnockoutJS, and the `.js` file is different than my `.cshtml`. file.

Comment: You have 2 possibilities: load it with AJAX or declare a global javascript variable in your view which will contain the JSON encoded data (as you currently have) and then in your separate .js file simply use this global variable.

Comment: What would ***you*** do in this case? Global variable maybe?

Comment: Both cases are acceptable. It would depend on whether you want the information immediately or you could allow for an AJAX request. It would really depend on your application specific requirements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32419/discussion-between-chiefgui-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336430/what-exactly-is-improved-in-mvc3-pertaining-to-validation